# Back button on the image preview

Tags: html

I have a minor problem, i just want a simple image preview with a go back button or something similar, I made

```
<div id="image1">
   <a href="../assets/image_large1.jpg"><img src="../assets/image_1.jpg"  width="160" height="107" alt="Example 1" /> 
</div>
```

but I don't know how to put a button inside

how could I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What should the back button do? I'm afraid you're going to have to give us more than that!

Comment: You have to make a new page for this, if you want to have button next to the large image. And you didn't close your `a` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most simple solution to your problem, I would do special `show_image.php` page, for example:

```
<?php

$directory = 'assets/';
$filename = $_GET['image'];

if(empty($filename) || is_file( $directory . $filename ))
{
    echo 'No such image!';
}
else
{
    echo '<img src="' . $directory . $filename . '" />';
}
echo '<br />';
echo '<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">Go back</a>';

exit;
```

And link for the image will be: http://mysite.com/show_image.php?image=image_1.jpg
Of course this code should be made more secure and this thing could be done other ways.